# grid inside scrollviewer in windows phone 7.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

i need a registeration form within my application, i need scrolling so i did the following

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="780" MaxHeight="1800"
                  MaxWidth="477" VerticalAlignment="Top">
           <ScrollViewer.Content>
          <Grid Width="477" Height="728"  MaxHeight="1800">  
                  <!--   .......Form's Elements..... -->
                 </Grid>
      </ScrollViewer.Content>
</ScrollViewer>
```

there is no scrolling, what am i missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't set the height properties when working with a `ScrollViewer`. If you strip it down to just the following and it still doesn't work, then it is something else in your project that is preventing it to work.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" FontSize="320" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="World" FontSize="320" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ScrollViewer.Content - part, I have an app that has this structure and it works fine:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentScrollViewer" Margin="0,0,0,8">
    <Grid Height="562">
        <!-- My elements -->
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: this line was added after many many desperate tries, anyhow, i removed it am still getting the same exact behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollviewer has a height of 780 and your grid is only 728. Why would there be any scrolling? You'll only be able to scroll if the grid is higher than 780.